# worpdress: how to call a function when a scheduled post is published?

Tags: wordpress

I am using wordpress.

I need to run a function (send a email) when a scheduled post is automatically posted.

What hook/function should I use ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [post status transition hooks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions)

```
function scheduled_post_published($object) 
{
    // whatever it is you need to do
}
add_action('future_to_publish', 'scheduled_post_published');
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the hook `transition_post_status`,  [from the documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status_Transitions#transition_post_status_Hook):

> `transition_post_status` is a generic action that is called every time a post changes status.

And on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/100657 I found piece of code that can you use as inspiration.